# How to use all_col_comments and user_col_comments in Oracle11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, comments, database-table, database-metadata

I have used the following statement to add the comment:

***comment on column employee.first_name
is 'first name of the employee table';***

No I have difficulty in knowing how to use **all_col_comments** and **user_col_comments** to view the above comment using select statement.

Comment: I get the result if for all the tables when I  use the query  "select * from user_col_comments".  However I want to retrieve the output only for employee table.

Comment: Hi, have you come across the `WHERE` clause before? You can restrict this to `where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'`. I would highly recommend doing some basic online tutorials first...

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `table_name` in the **filter predicate**.

For example,

```
select * from all_col_comments where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';
```

The view has four columns:

- OWNER
- TABLE_NAME
- COLUMN_NAME
- COMMENTS

Read more about the view in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1030.htm#REFRN20040).